# Is http://tromey.com/elpa/ deprecated?

Tags: package-repositories

Long time ago I added:

```
(setq package-archives '(("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
```

In http://tromey.com/elpa/elpa.rss latest package is from `2010-08-15 22:11`.

Is that right that modern package repositories are:

```
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("marmalade" . "https://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

**UPDATE** Seems that Tom Tromey is initial author of `package.el` http://tromey.com/blog/?page_id=333

Comment: Maybe ask Tom? `tom@tromey.com`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tom Tromey, who happens to be the author of package.el, put up the very first ELPA which is still available on his domain.  However [you should no longer use it](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3m3j3n/whats_up_with_tromeycom/) and instead just refer to GNU ELPA which happens to be the default repository in `package-archives`.  Maybe add another package archive while you're at it ;)